# Package blindtext not producing inline math

Tags: blindtext

The docs for `blindtext.sty` say to use option `math` to add some math, and command `\blindmathtrue` to cause the following blind text to contain *inline* math.

However, I get no math whatsoever, inline or displayed, from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindmathtrue
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no math setup in the latin text. But if you use e.g. english (by using babel) it appears:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's rather nicely obscured in the documentation!